# Grouping/identify similar names

Tags: r

I have a large data set (17.000 cases) with 9.000 distinct company names. However, most of the names are duplicates/misspellings.

Is there a way to identify the duplicates/misspellings by an algorithm?

At the moment I use `grepl` to identify the duplicates. Like:

```
dat %>%
select(Company) %>%
filter(grepl("g&s|g & s", ignore.case = T, Company)) %>%
distinct()

# A tibble: 15 x 1
 Company                                                  
   <chr>                                                    
 1 das projekt Projektmanagement, Consulting & Services GmbH
 2 G&S Vastgoed                                             
 3 G&S Bouw                                                                                      
 5 G&S                                                      
 6 G&S Hotelbetriebs GmbH                                   
 7 BCadvies - G&S                                           
 8 G&s Bouw                                                 
 9 G&S bouw
```

After that, I standardize the names like:

```
dat = dat %>%
  mutate(Company = ifelse(grepl("g&s|g & s", ignore.case = T, Company), "G & S", Company))
```

Comment: There are many! Some relevant terms of art include "entity resolution" and "record linkage."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when I had to deal with that problem in R I started here https://www.r-bloggers.com/fuzzy-string-matching-a-survival-skill-to-tackle-unstructured-information/

Currently I am using the `fuzzywuzzyR` https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/fuzzywuzzyR/index.html